# Understanding the vector potential associated to the electromagnetic wave propagating in a single direction

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, potential

I am doing an exercise in the book Modern Geometric Structure and Fields, Novikov and Taimanov.

The setting is in the Minkowski space $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$ with coordinate $(x^0=ct,x^1,x^2,x^3)$.

> Exercise 4 in chapter 9: Let the charge density $\rho$ be equal to zero, and let the vector potential of the electromagnetic field $A_i$ have the form $A_i(x-c t), i=0,1,2,3$ (electromagnetic wave propagating along the $x$-axis). Prove that all the eigenvalues of the electromagnetic field are identically equal to zero.

My first question is: What does it mean for $A_i(x-ct)$? Suppose that it means
$$
A_{i}(x^1-ct) = A_i(x^1-x^0).
$$

The eigenvalue is defined as follows:

> 7.4.2. Eigenvalues of scalar products. Suppose in a vector space there is a scalar product specified by a tensor $T_{i j}$ and a metric specified by a tensor $g_{i j}$. The eigenvalues of the scalar product $T_{i j}$ in the metric $g_{i j}$ are defined as the solutions to the equation
> $$
> P(\lambda)=\operatorname{det}\left(T_{i j}-\lambda g_{i j}\right)=0 .
> $$

In this case, the electromagnetic field can be computed as $F_{ij} = \partial_{i}A_{j} - \partial_{j}A_{i}$ and thus
$$
(F_{ij}) = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -A_1'-A_0'& -A_2'& -A_3'\\
A_1'+A_0' & 0 & A_2' & A_3'\\
A_2' & -A_2' & 0 & 0\\
A_3' & -A_3' & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Then, we compute $\det(F_{ij}-\lambda g_{ij})$ which is givem by
$$
-\lambda^{4}+(A_1'+A_0')^2\lambda^2.
$$
I cannot see the correct conclusion that all the eigenvalues are zero. Any help for me to understand this correctly?

Moreover, for this exercise, a remark states This is the case of electromagnetic waves propagated in a single direction. I also don't understand what this means.

Comment: Your first question is correct. In particular, you have correctly noted that it would not depend upon $y$ nor $z$, as is obvious in the matrix you computed. I am not going to vet if you have computed everything correctly, but I have to point out that you seem to not have computed the Maxwell's equations. You need that to show more stuff to be zero; indeed, I think $A^\prime_1+A^\prime_0=0$ or something like that.

Comment: *This is the case of electromagnetic waves propagated in a single direction. I also don't understand what this means.* This wave is a function of $x-ct$ so it is moving in the $\hat x$ direction. An example of a wave that doesn’t move in a single direction would be a radial wave that is a function of $r-ct$; it would be moving in all directions.